Tikzpicture with subcaption
I would like to make the following figure:

I received the code for a somewhat similar figure here Tikzpicture with subfigures and caption but don't manage to change this to the desired format as shown above.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{subfigure a}[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\length{6}   % Length of your arrow
        \def\height{0.5} % Height of your intersections
        \draw[->] (-\length,0) -- (\length,0);
        \node at (-2*\length/3,0) [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{X};
        \node at ( 0,0)           [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{Y};
        \node at ( 2*\length/3,0) [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{Z};
        \draw[-] (-\length/3,-\height/2) -- (-\length/3,\height/2);
        \draw[-] ( \length/3,-\height/2) -- ( \length/3,\height/2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{subfigure b}[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\length{6}   % Length of your arrow
        \def\height{0.5} % Height of your intersections
        \draw[->] (-\length,0) -- (\length,0);
        \node at (-2*\length/3,0) [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{X};
        \node at ( 0,0)           [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{Y};
        \node at ( 2*\length/3,0) [yshift=-4,anchor=north]{Z};
        \draw[-] (-\length/3,-\height/2) -- (-\length/3,\height/2);
        \draw[-] ( \length/3,-\height/2) -- ( \length/3,\height/2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}


It is better to use the subcaption block environment that will allow you to vary the vertical separation between figures I use \captionsetup{skip=2em}, then also using this environment you can control whether the captions go below or above, this is defined if you put the caption before or after the drawing; In the case of the drawing you propose, I have created 3 drawing definitions so as not to have to specify the styles and coordinates a lot of times. The first \Xdoms, allows you to place marks in positions relative to a factor between 0 and 1 of the indicated length, in this case the width of the text line \linewidht, that way you can place the marks better, each mark must have a name, a content and a color, the names will be used for other drawing definitions so as not to be placing absolute coordinates.
The second \Acot, draws a dimension between 2 marks defined using their names, remember that in \xdoms there are 2 named coordinates that are name and name-up, which is where the dimensions will begin, then the content goes in text nodes in the middle (pos=0.5) and above the path.
The last one is used to place the midpoint "x" which uses the tikz library calc with the method $(#1)!0.5!(#2)$, locates the midpoint between 2 nodes that can be entered as names as well, then a circle is drawn and defined a text node but instead of placing the corresponding text I use a node label which I can place at a certain distance label distance=0.7em from the node in a specific orientation -90.
By doing this all cases can be drawn, including an additional one as a playground, obviously you must first use \xdoms, and then the rest since they use the names of the coordinates that are created in each mark entered.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\def\Xdoms#1#2#3{%\Xdoms{length}{height}{Markers{position/name/content/color}}
    \draw(0,0)--++(#1,0);
    \foreach \position/\name/\content/\color in {#3}{
        \draw[draw=\color,thick]
        (#1*\position,0)++(0,#2/2)
            -- ++(0,-#2) node[below, minimum height=2em,inner sep=0]{\content};
        \coordinate (\name-up) at (#1*\position,#2*1.5);
        \coordinate (\name) at (#1*\position,0);
    }
}

\def\Acot#1#2#3#4{
    \draw[draw=#4,|-|](#1)--(#2)node [pos=0.5,above]{#3};
}
\def\Dotx#1#2#3#4{
    \fill[fill=#4]($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$) circle (3.5pt) node[below,label={[label distance=0.7em,#4]-90:#3}]{};
}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{figure}{4}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption {figure name}  
        \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \Xdoms{\linewidth}{0.5}{
                    0/Mk-0/0/black,%\position/\name/\content/\color
                    0.45/Mk-a/a/black,
                    0.65/Mk-b/b/black,
                    1/Mk-1/1/black%
                }
                \Acot{Mk-0-up}{Mk-a-up}{Text\_1}{red}
                \Acot{Mk-b-up}{Mk-1-up}{Text\_2}{blue}
                \Dotx{Mk-b}{Mk-1}{x}{black} 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionsetup{skip=2em}
            \caption{Sub figure a}
        \end{subcaptionblock}
        \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \Xdoms{\linewidth}{0.5}{
                    0/Mk-0/0/black,%\position/\name/\content/\color
                    0.5/Mk-a/a/black,
                    1/Mk-1/1/black%
                }
                \Acot{Mk-0-up}{Mk-a-up}{Text\_1}{red}
                \Acot{Mk-a-up}{Mk-1-up}{Text\_2}{blue}
                \Dotx{Mk-a}{Mk-1}{x}{black} 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionsetup{skip=2em}
            \caption{Sub figure b}
        \end{subcaptionblock}
        \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \Xdoms{\linewidth}{0.5}{
                    0/Mk-0/0/black,%\position/\name/\content/\color
                    1/Mk-1/1/black%
                }
                \Acot{Mk-0-up}{Mk-1-up}{Text\_2}{blue}
                \Dotx{Mk-0}{Mk-1}{x}{black} 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionsetup{skip=2em}
            \caption{Sub figure c}
        \end{subcaptionblock}
        \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \Xdoms{\linewidth}{0.5}{
                    0/AA/A/red,%\position/\name/\content/\color
                    0.1/BB/B/black!20!red,
                    0.3/CC/C/black!30!red,
                    0.4/DD/D/black!40!red,
                    0.5/EE/E/black!50!red,
                    0.75/FF/F/black!60!red,
                    1/GG/G/black!70!red%
                }
                \Acot{AA-up}{CC-up}{A TO C}{blue}
                \Acot{DD-up}{FF-up}{D TO F}{blue!50!red}
                \Dotx{AA}{BB}{x}{green!50!blue}
                \Dotx{EE}{FF}{y}{green!50!cyan} 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionsetup{skip=2em}
            \caption{Sub figure d playground}
        \end{subcaptionblock}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


This is what I get from your code.

I couldn't get what is the problem related to subcaptions. Is it with the tikz ilustration itself? Do you want to get the very same figure?
Please, clarify your question.

If you want to place texts in "text_1" and "text_2" placeholders, I recommend using \node inside the tikzpicture environment.
